# Connection aborted when unit test to request to docker container built in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, docker, python-requests, dockerpy

My goal is to write a unit test that builds a docker container and tries to execute a request to the newly built container.

The test first builds an docker image, then runs the image and finally tries to execute a request to the newly created container. Currently running the test using `py.test` gives me

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))
```

whereas running the same code in ipython works just fine.

*Expected behavior:* `py.test` gives a successful result.

### Test

```
import pytest
import docker
import requests

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def docker_env():
    return docker.from_env()

@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def docker_image(docker_env):
    client = docker_env
    image = client.images.build(path = ".", tag = "python-test:latest")
    yield image, client
    client.images.remove("python-test:latest")

def test_port(docker_image):
    image, client = docker_image
    client.containers.run("python-test:latest", 
                          entrypoint="/opt/conda/envs/python-docker-test/bin/gunicorn --config /usr/src/app/gunicorn.conf.py app:api",
                          detach=True,
                          ports={'8000/tcp': ('127.0.0.1', 8000)})

    resp = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello")
    assert resp.status == 200
    # Expect success, currently getting an error
```

### Dockerfile

My docker file looks as follows,

```
FROM phusion/baseimage:0.9.22
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8 LC_ALL=C.UTF-8

RUN apt-get update --fix-missing && apt-get install -y wget bzip2 ca-certificates \
    libglib2.0-0 libxext6 libsm6 libxrender1 \
    git mercurial subversion

RUN echo 'export PATH=/opt/conda/bin:$PATH' > /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    wget --quiet https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-4.3.30-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/conda && \
    rm ~/miniconda.sh

ENV PATH /opt/conda/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .

RUN conda env create -f environment.yml

EXPOSE 8000

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENTRYPOINT  source activate python-docker-test && /opt/conda/envs/python-docker-test/bin/gunicorn \
  --config /usr/src/app/gunicorn.conf.py  app:api
```

### app.py

```
import falcon

class TestServer:
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        resp.content_type = "text/text"

        resp.body = "hello world"
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_OK

api = falcon.API()
api.add_route("/hello", TestServer())
```

### environment.yml

```
name: python-docker-test
channels:
 - anaconda
 - conda-forge
dependencies:
 - python==3.6
 - gunicorn==19.7.1
 - pytest==3.2.5
 - gunicorn==19.7.1
 - ipython
 - falcon==1.3.0
 - pip==9.0.1
 - pip:
   - docker==2.7.0
```

### Gunicorn.conf.py

```
bind = '0.0.0.0:8000'
```

### System specs

- Server Version: 17.12.0-ce
- uname: 17.3.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.3.0

Comment: If the Docker takes more than a few fractions of a second to set up the port, you probably have to wait a while for the server to be able to respond to your request. The quick and dirty workaround is to `time.sleep(1)` before attempting to connect. The proper solution would be for the container to be able to somehow tell you when it's ready. (Retrying a few times with a sleep between is probably a pretty robust approach. This tends to turn around and bite you when you break the server and your code keeps on retrying forever and you can't see what it's doing.)

Comment: That  was super helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right test looks like,

```
def test_port(docker_image):
    image, client = docker_image
    import time
    container = client.containers.run("python-test:latest",
                                      detach=True,
                                      ports={'8000/tcp': ('127.0.0.1', 8000)})

    time.sleep(1)
    resp = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello")

    container.kill()
    assert resp.status_code == 200
```